# How can i check if values of models are the same in django loop?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've a loop:

```
{% for addimg in post.addimg_set.all %}
    <p> 
    {{ addimg.execution }}<br>
    {{ addimg.width }} cm x {{ addimg.height }} cm<br>
    {{ addimg.year }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to display some data as long as they are different. If they are equal i want it only to display once like:

```
{% if addimg.execution == addimg.execution %}
    {{ addimg.execution }}<br>
{% endif %}
```

forgive me my python/django still young.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find your answer in documentation.

Check this out:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `{% ifchanged %}` template tag.

```
{% ifchanged addimg.execution %}
    {{ addimg.execution }}<br>
{% endifchanged %}
```